# Bootstrap two column misalignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a simple two column layout, but for some reason, some of the cells get skipped. (see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU6Ux.jpg). I am using Laravel to get the products from the DB using a foreach loop. The code for one product looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 mt-4">
<div class="card">
    <img src="{{asset('storage/app/public/cover_images/'.$product->cover_image)}}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h6 class="text-center">ROMÂNĂ</h6>
                <h4 class="mt-4 text-center">
                    <b>{{$product->name_ro}}</b></h4>
                <p>{{$product->desc_ro}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h6 class="text-center">ENGLISH</h6>
                <h4 class="mt-4 text-center">
                    <b>{{$product->name_en}}</b></h4>
                <p>{{$product->desc_en}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5 class="text-center">Pret: <b>{{$product->price}}</b>
        </h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
            <a href="{{url('/products/'.$product->id.'/edit/')}}">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Editeaza</button></a>
            <form action="{{ action('ProductsController@destroy', $product->id) }}" method="post">
                @csrf
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sterge</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code above is generated for every product there is. Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a simple example because i cannot render your screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a problem could be, that your `<h4>` text is not always the same length.
The headlines are pushing the content, and the cards are receiving different height values.
If you set a fixed height for h4, your problem is maybe solved.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, you're a genius. I was looking for a problem with my CSS but couldn't see any. Cheers!